# Should this question about spellcasting be open or closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicates

- [Do I understand how spell slots work for druids and sorcerers correctly?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/180163)

The above question was originally closed, and now has four reopen votes (though in the review queue it has three votes to be left closed). There are two rather different comments under it:

> Each question here should be a single question, and an artefact here is that I think some of these questions are dupes of question already asked. [...]

> The linked questions together provide answers to all parts of this question, but I voted to reopen, because a general and directed answer to the issue of "am I understanding this correctly" is exactly what we should answer in a single place on this stack.

For reference, the "linked questions" this refers to are the following (probably):

- [Can a spell be prepared once and cast multiple times?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/44736)
- [How do I determine how many spell slots I have when multiclassing?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/167040)
- [If I multiclass into 2 or more spellcasting classes, how do I determine my known/prepared spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/151000)
- [I don't get the spell slot system for D&D 5e's Warlocks](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103637)
- [How does wizard & cleric spell preparation and casting work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/44400)
- [How long do a spellcaster's prepared spells stay prepared?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/135599)
- [Can you have more spells known of a certain spell level than you have spell slots of that level?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/141970)
- [How does adding Spells Known and Spell Slots work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/119076)
- [Do class spells take up spell slots?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/113925)

Going back to the comment though, these are, of course, rather different. I *personally* feel the question should either be closed with various duplicate targets (one for each question it asks) *or* be closed as needing to be more focused (it asks multiple questions); however, I am just one person, and am not deadset on that being the only option here. What I don't want to do is to hammer-close the question and cause a close/reopen hammer war.

So I'm asking this here: Should this question be open or closed?

Answer (score 13):

### I suggest it’s better for everyone to just leave this open

Those are all closely-related questions; while 1 question per Question is a guideline that we should adhere to strongly, there *are* exceptions, and this can reasonably be called one of them.

Further, it is **really hard** to close “do I understand this correctly?” questions as duplicates—and most of the time, we’re better off not bothering. That’s because two different unsure people rarely have exactly the same misunderstandings about the material in question. Usually we need to address their specific interpretation, which is very hard to duplicate. Furthermore, often the askers of these sorts of questions have a hard time understanding someone else’s uncertain interpretation—directing them to similar questions can just cause more confusion than it helps.

In D&D 3.5e and Pathfinder, we have a *ton* of questions that amount to “did I calculate the price of this magic item right?” and we don’t close them as duplicates because it’s harder to explain how to extrapolate from one case to another than it is to just answer their specific question. Likewise here, where the pairing is druid and sorcerer, and I suspect this querent could very well be confused by very-similar questions about clerics and wizards.

Comment: Now this would be a great addition to an faq.